# $_post inside for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, isset

im trying to play around in php, and its not going too well. I am trying to change a string through input fields in html

HTML PART

```
<form action="index2.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="text"><?php echo $search_replace; ?></textarea><br>
search<br><input type="text" name="search"><br>
replace<br><input type="text" name="replace">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

php part

```
$text = $_POST[text];
$search = $_POST[search];
$replace = $_POST[replace];
$search_replace = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

this works, but i wanted to try to put all the variables in a for loop just to try new things out. this is what i ended up with (probably should have used foreach):

```
$field = array('text', 'search', 'replace');
for($i = 0; i > 3; $i++) {
 if(isset($_POST[$field[$i]]) &&!empty($_POST[$field[$i]])) {
 $field[$i] = $_POST[$field[$i]];
 }
}
$search_replace = str_replace($field[1], $field[2], $field[0]);
```

$field[0] still has 'text' in it. shouldnt the value after the for loop be $_POST[$field[0]]? Do i need to create seperate arrays? one with the name of the fields and one empty to store $_POST[field[i]]?

Comment: Shouldn't `$i` be lower than 3 instead of higher than 3?

Comment: Does that loop actually work? `for ($i = 0; i > 3; $i++)` should really be `for ($i =0; $i < 3; $i++)`... With a dollar sign, and reversed inequality.

Comment: You declare $i with 0. then you say, $i > 3. But $i is smaller than 3. It should be. ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++). I also recall you can only use a variable in !empty().(not really sure about the latter)

Comment: Also you forgot the '$' for the second 'i' in your for loop

Comment: and in the php part you should enclose the index names with quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) 
{
     if(isset($_POST[$field[$i]]) &&!empty($_POST[$field[$i]])) {
     $field[$i] = $_POST[$field[$i]];
}
```

In your code the loop was like this:

```
for($i = 0; i > 3; $i++)
```

In which you forgot to add **$** symbol before the the second 'i' in your for loop.

And the second condition was `$i > 3`. 
You initialized $i as 0 and is checking whether $i is greater than 3, and if it is greater than 3, you increment $i, which is never going to happen as $i is 0 initially.

So it must be `$i<3`

Comment: Copy problem! Forgot the dollar sign.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos Cleared :-)

Comment: what have you changed and why is this code now right? Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: wow i feel really dumb now, thanks for the answer. so the code really worked. nice

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
<?php
$posted = array();
if (! empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $pk => $pv) {
        if (! empty($k)) {
            $posted[$pk] = $pv;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Because, `$_POST` is itself an array. And it has keys and values.

If a form element is posted, we get it by `$_POST['varName']` means,

We are accessing the key `varname` of `$_POST`

Also, we are checking that its not empty. So only those variables will be extracted which are posted.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($posted);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: why do you think this is the right answer? Please elaborate with some explanation.

Comment: Also please explain that this code will assign any value that any user might post, allowing XSS.